# Map function not displaying data properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mapping

I use to Map method to display data form API but data is not aligned properly I apply reverse method to reverse data but reverse is not working properly

I create this function to display data:

```
   const blogCategory = (item) => {
       return( 
      <>   
       <div>
          <div  key={item.title} className="mx-3" style= 
          {{display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",height:"750px"}}>
  
          <div className="blog bolg-post">
          <div className="img-hover-zoom">
          <Link href={`/blogs/${item.title.replace(urlR,"-").replace('?',"")}`}>
           <img style={{cursor:"pointer"}} className="blog-box" src={item.urlToImage}/>
           </Link> 
            </div>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <span className="name-blog">{item.category}</span>
                        <Link href={`/blogs/${item.title.replace(urlR,"-").replace('?',"")}`}>
                        <span style={{cursor: "pointer",textAlign:"justify",maxHeight:"62px",overflow:"hidden"}} className="heading-blog">{item.title}</span>
                        </Link>
                        <div style={{height:"100px",overflow:"hidden",textAlign:"justify"}} className="para-blog">{item.meta_description}</div>
                        {/* <div style={{height:"100px",overflow:"hidden",textAlign:"justify"}} className="para-blog" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }}/> */}
                        <Link href={`/blogs/${item.title.replace(urlR,"-").replace('?',"")}`}>
                        <button className="btn-blog mt-3">{item.readingTime}&#160;min read</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div> 
          </div>
      </div>
</div>

</>
   )
   }
```

I use Map method to display data by using this function as show in below:

```
 <div className='d-flex col-12' style={{width:"1000px"}}>
       <div  style={{height:"650px",overflow:'hidden'}}>
         {cat.filter(categ=>categ.category === 'technology').reverse().map(
          blogCategory
       
    )}
  </div>
  <div className="products">
    {cat.filter(categ=>categ.category === 'technology').map(
        productCategory
    )}
   </div> 
</div>
```

Data is displaying properly but does not align like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] it displays like [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] .

Comment: For the blogCategory you reverse, for the productCategory you don't

Comment: because nothing happens on adding reverse it's not working